# 7x7 Prewitt Kernel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, computer-vision

I am fairly new Image processing and wanted to do a filtering using a larger Prewitt kernel. Problem is I can't find anything bigger than the 3x3 kernel on wikipedia. I have also seen a 4x4 kernel on a class presentation, but am totally clueless on how it was evaluated. Could someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure there is fixed definition of what the 7x7 Prewitt kernel is? [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567882/sobel-filter-kernel-of-large-size) asking about 7x7 Sobel kernels suggests that the larger versions of these kernels are defined on an ad hoc basis based on the user.

Comment: See [this .pdf](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iasj.net%2Fiasj%3Ffunc%3Dfulltext%26aId%3D52927&ei=fZwcVNylK4jmaLL4gogE&usg=AFQjCNHeNhHXPtrLRj3CoICdI5N6rzE-3A&bvm=bv.75775273,d.d2s&cad=rja) for a 5x5. Good luck expanding to 7x7!

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I am frankly not sure if it's there. But I am guessing it should be there. I did read of the method of the method to get bigger sorbel kernels, but wasn't sure if I could do the same to expand prewitt

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer directly your question, but I came across this some time go and it might be of interest as it follows @AnonSubmitter85's comment.

Based on a paper which can be found [here](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~raghuram/ENEE731/EdgeDetection/Haralick_ZeroCrossing.pdf), there are many 'ways' to define a kernel of a given size since they used to describe polynomials (or linear combinations of polynomials) which describe functions from which directional derivatives of an image are computed. I admit that I don't understand everything, anyhow here are the possible windows that can be produced for kernels of size

1) 3x3

[image]

or

2) 4x4

[image]

So I guess there is no single 7x7 kernel that can be computed. Since the Sobel and Prewitt are very miuch alike, there is a submission on the File Exchange which might interest you. Here is the code, which is pretty short. It creates a generalised Sobel filter of any size (I don't have any credit for it, I just paste the code so it's simpler for you to get :).

```
%Program for creating generalised Sobel operator
%Authors : Jeny Rajan, K.Kannan
%Medical Imaging Research Group, NeST, Trivandrum 
%http://jenyrajan.googlepages.com/
%http://kannan.keizer.googlepages.com/kannankeizer 

%This program can be used to generate sobel filter of any order
% Usage  [E Mx My]=Gsobel(img,Wsize)
% eg. [E Mx My]=Gsobel(img,5)
% E - Resultant Edge image generated with sobel filter of window size Wsize
% Mx & My  - Horizontal and Vertical Masks 
% img - input image
% Wsize - Filter window size

function [E Mx My]= GSobel(img,Wsize)
for i=1:Wsize
    Sx(i)=factorial((Wsize-1))/((factorial((Wsize-1)-(i-1)))*(factorial(i-1)));
    Dx(i)=Pasc(i-1,Wsize-2)-Pasc(i-2,Wsize-2);
end
Sy=Sx';
Dy=Dx';
Mx=Sy(:)*Dx;
My=Mx';
Ey=imfilter(double(img),My,'symmetric');
Ex=imfilter(double(img),Mx,'symmetric');
E=sqrt(Ex.^2+Ey.^2);
figure,imshow(img,[]),title('Original Image');
figure,imshow(E,[]),title('Edge Image');

function P=Pasc(k,n)
if (k>=0)&&(k<=n)
    P=factorial(n)/(factorial(n-k)*factorial(k));
else
    P=0;
end
```

Sorry if my answer is quite long and does not really solve your problem, but it was obviously too long for a comment! Hope that helps somehow.