# Does opencv Sobel operator compute correlation?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, sobel

Does opencv Sobel operator compute  correlation, not the convolution?
I know that the filter2D function computes correlation and i just found out (based from the results of the code)that the Sobel operator also computes correlation. Is this expected? AM i missing something here?

```
Mat sobelx, dest1,dest2;
Sobel(src, sobelx, src.depth(),1,0,3);
imshow("Sobel filtered in x dir" ,sobelx);
Mat kern = (Mat_<float>(3,3)<<-1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,1);
filter2D(src,dest1,src.type(),kern);
imshow("Sobel in x-dir using corr ", dest1);
/* dest1 equals sobelx  */
flip(kern,kern, -1);//flip the kernel in x and y direction for convolution
filter2D(src,dest2,src.type(),kern);
imshow("Sobel in x-dir using conv ",dest2,);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the test that i wrote and the output tells the truth.
**cv::Sobel computes correlation and not convolution.**
I have used the following kernel which is the same as used by cv::Sobel

```
kern = [-1, 0, 1;
        -2, 0, 2;
        -1, 0, 1]
```

The results show that the output of sobelx and filter2d(correlation) is same.

```
void test_sobel(){
cv::RNG(0);
cv::Mat src(4,4, CV_8U);
cv::randu(src, 0, 256);
cv::Mat sobelx, dest_corr,dest_conv;
cv::Sobel(src, sobelx, CV_32F,1,0,3);
// sobel uses a 3x3 filter shown as below
Mat kern = (Mat_<float>(3,3)<<-1,0,1,-2,0,2,-1,0,1);
// filter2D computes correlation
cv::filter2D(src,dest_corr,CV_32F,kern);

//flip the kernel in x and y direction for convolution
cv::Mat kern_conv;
cv::flip(kern,kern_conv, -1);
cv::filter2D(src,dest_conv,CV_32F,kern_conv);

std::cout << "kern = \n" << kern<< std::endl;
std::cout << "kern_conv = \n" << kern_conv<< std::endl;
std::cout << "src = \n" << src << std::endl;
std::cout << "sobelx = \n" << sobelx<< std::endl;
std::cout << "dest_corr = \n" << dest_corr<< std::endl;
std::cout << "dest_conv =\n" << dest_conv << std::endl;
cv::Mat diff1 = sobelx - dest_corr;
cv::Mat diff2 = sobelx - dest_conv;
std::cout << "sobelx - dest_corr = " << cv::sum( diff1 )[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "sobelx - dest_conv = " << cv::sum( diff2 )[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
kern = 
[-1, 0, 1;
 -2, 0, 2;
-1, 0, 1]
kern_conv = 
[1, 0, -1;
 2, 0, -2;
 1, 0, -1]
src = 
[246, 156, 192,   7;
 165, 166,   2, 179;
 231, 212, 171, 230;
  93, 138, 123,  80]
sobelx = 
[0, -434, -272, 0;
 0, -440, -105, 0;
 0, -253, -9, 0;
 0, -60, -80, 0]
dest_corr = 
[0, -434, -272, 0;
 0, -440, -105, 0;
 0, -253, -9, 0;
 0, -60, -80, 0]
dest_conv =
[0, 434, 272, 0;
 0, 440, 105, 0;
 0, 253, 9, 0;
 0, 60, 80, 0]
sobelx - dest_corr = 0
sobelx - dest_conv = -3306
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

To get the OpenCV Sobel kernels, you can call [`cv::getDerivKernels`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga6d6c23f7bd3f5836c31cfae994fc4aea) to get the two separable kernels (it is `cv::sepFilter2D` that is in fact called in the OpenCV code of `cv::Sobel`, or Intel IPP Sobel or any other backend if presents) and indeed a correlation is performed.

The kernel mentionned below is obsolete but the test code can still be useful!

---

The best option is to test to avoid surprise:

```
{
    cv::RNG(0); //fix RNG

    cv::Mat img(8, 8, CV_8U);
    cv::randu(img, 0, 256);

    cv::Mat sobel_x;
    cv::Sobel(img, sobel_x, CV_64F, 1, 0);

    cv::Mat sobel_filter;
    cv::Mat kern = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1, 0, -1,
                                              2, 0, -2,
                                              1, 0, -1);
    cv::filter2D(img, sobel_filter, CV_64F, kern);

    cv::Mat kern_flip, sobel_filter_conv;
    cv::flip(kern, kern_flip, -1);
    cv::filter2D(img, sobel_filter_conv, CV_64F, kern_flip);

    std::cout << "img:\n" << img << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sobel_x:\n" << sobel_x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sobel_filter:\n" << sobel_filter << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sobel_filter_conv:\n" << sobel_filter_conv << std::endl;

    cv::Mat diff = sobel_x - sobel_filter;
    cv::Mat diff2 = sobel_x - sobel_filter_conv;
    std::cout << "Diff sobel_x - sobel_filter: " << cv::sum( diff )[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Diff sobel_x - sobel_filter_conv: " << cv::sum( diff2 )[0] << std::endl;
}


{
    cv::RNG(0); //fix RNG

    cv::Mat img(8, 8, CV_8U);
    cv::randu(img, 0, 256);

    cv::Mat sobel_y;
    cv::Sobel(img, sobel_y, CV_64F, 0, 1);

    cv::Mat sobel_filter;
    cv::Mat kern = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1,  2,  1,
                                              0,  0,  0,
                                             -1, -2, -1);
    cv::filter2D(img, sobel_filter, CV_64F, kern);

    cv::Mat kern_flip, sobel_filter_conv;
    cv::flip(kern, kern_flip, -1);
    cv::filter2D(img, sobel_filter_conv, CV_64F, kern_flip);

    std::cout << "img:\n" << img << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sobel_y:\n" << sobel_y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sobel_filter:\n" << sobel_filter << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sobel_filter_conv:\n" << sobel_filter_conv << std::endl;

    cv::Mat diff = sobel_y - sobel_filter;
    cv::Mat diff2 = sobel_y - sobel_filter_conv;
    std::cout << "Diff sobel_y - sobel_filter: " << cv::sum( diff )[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Diff sobel_y - sobel_filter_conv: " << cv::sum( diff2 )[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
img:
[246, 156, 192,   7, 165, 166,   2, 179;
 231, 212, 171, 230,  93, 138, 123,  80;
 105, 242, 231, 239, 174, 174, 176, 191;
 134,  54, 234,  69,  25, 147,  24,  67;
 124, 158, 203, 206,  89, 144, 210,  51;
  31, 132, 123, 250, 234, 246, 204,  74;
 111, 208, 249, 149, 234,  37,  55, 147;
 143,  29, 214, 169, 215,  84, 190, 204]
sobel_x:
[0, -228, -262, -210, 134, -266, -90, 0;
 0, -48, -116, -240, -90, -101, -86, 0;
 0, 292, 27, -401, -144, 33, -104, 0;
 0, 405, 75, -589, 29, 121, -236, 0;
 0, 350, 229, -326, -50, 211, -438, 0;
 0, 401, 225, 93, -182, -118, -327, 0;
 0, 439, 140, 82, -313, -413, 168, 0;
 0, 418, 162, -28, -394, -408, 460, 0]
sobel_filter:
[0, 228, 262, 210, -134, 266, 90, 0;
 0, 48, 116, 240, 90, 101, 86, 0;
 0, -292, -27, 401, 144, -33, 104, 0;
 0, -405, -75, 589, -29, -121, 236, 0;
 0, -350, -229, 326, 50, -211, 438, 0;
 0, -401, -225, -93, 182, 118, 327, 0;
 0, -439, -140, -82, 313, 413, -168, 0;
 0, -418, -162, 28, 394, 408, -460, 0]
sobel_filter_conv:
[0, -228, -262, -210, 134, -266, -90, 0;
 0, -48, -116, -240, -90, -101, -86, 0;
 0, 292, 27, -401, -144, 33, -104, 0;
 0, 405, 75, -589, 29, 121, -236, 0;
 0, 350, 229, -326, -50, 211, -438, 0;
 0, 401, 225, 93, -182, -118, -327, 0;
 0, 439, 140, 82, -313, -413, 168, 0;
 0, 418, 162, -28, -394, -408, 460, 0]
Diff sobel_x - sobel_filter: -3428
Diff sobel_x - sobel_filter_conv: 0

img:
[110, 239, 216, 103, 137, 248, 173,  53;
 221, 142,  83, 166, 251, 222, 243,  67;
  29, 232, 208, 159, 115,  91, 244, 128;
 151, 254,  47,  13, 132, 253, 137, 127;
 180, 181, 179, 168, 236, 246,  66, 169;
 188, 198, 198, 137, 131,  63,   5, 237;
 220, 209, 155,  88,  28,  12,  58,  99;
   6,  49, 196, 195, 163,   9,  82, 197]
sobel_y:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 -176, -103, 33, 82, -145, -265, 60, 292;
 84, 118, -113, -461, -360, -163, -121, -92;
 200, 20, -100, 110, 406, 253, -160, -274;
 -38, 76, 370, 398, -68, -513, -344, -44;
 136, 72, -100, -392, -730, -684, -320, -156;
 -662, -482, -95, 146, 68, 1, 60, 74;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
sobel_filter:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 176, 103, -33, -82, 145, 265, -60, -292;
 -84, -118, 113, 461, 360, 163, 121, 92;
 -200, -20, 100, -110, -406, -253, 160, 274;
 38, -76, -370, -398, 68, 513, 344, 44;
 -136, -72, 100, 392, 730, 684, 320, 156;
 662, 482, 95, -146, -68, -1, -60, -74;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
sobel_filter_conv:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 -176, -103, 33, 82, -145, -265, 60, 292;
 84, 118, -113, -461, -360, -163, -121, -92;
 200, 20, -100, 110, 406, 253, -160, -274;
 -38, 76, 370, 398, -68, -513, -344, -44;
 136, 72, -100, -392, -730, -684, -320, -156;
 -662, -482, -95, 146, 68, 1, 60, 74;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Diff sobel_y - sobel_filter: -8204
Diff sobel_y - sobel_filter_conv: 0
```

Comment: Hi @Catree, your test proves again that the **cv::Sobel computes correlation and not convolution**.
The _kern_ that you have used in the code snippet is already flipped. Hence reversed results. Use the following kernel and you will get the actual results.
    cv::Mat kern = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << -1, 0, 1,
                                          -2, 0, 2,
                                          -1, 0, 1);
Here is the opencv doc which points to the standard Sobel kernel
[http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html]

Comment: I cannot find one consensus about the Sobel kernel (for example these sources give slightly different forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator ; http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~image529/TA529/Image529_99/assignments/edge_detection/references/sobel.htm ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567882/sobel-filter-kernel-of-large-size). For curiosity, why is it important for you?

Comment: Other sources: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/504204?language=en ; https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/filters/edges.py#L59 In my opinion, if you need exact results, just use `cv::filter2D` and the kernel of your choice.

Comment: There are definitely different flavors of sobel and all serve the purpose to detect the edge. However, we are comparing cv::sobel with cv::filter2D and opencv documentation mentions that it uses the one that i had mentioned earlier. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html
It matters to me as my end goal is to compute the gradient direction and use it thereafter.

Comment: I have to mention this paper: `An Isotropic 3x3 Image Gradient Operator` (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239398674_An_Isotropic_3_3_Image_Gradient_Operator) for the definition of the Sobel kernel. You will observe that almost every source have a slightly different kernel. So, I changed a little bit my answer.

Comment: I am not why the point of discussion here is focused on the flavors of kernels. The question here was to compare the cv::Sobel and cv::filter2D operation results. we all know that filter2D computes correlation and the standard kernel used by cv::Sobel for a size of 3 is {-1,0,1;-2,0,2;-1,0,1}. If we agree on this fact , than the answer is pretty obvious.