# Does cv2.Canny() perform a Gaussian blur?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

I know it's important to apply Gaussian blur to an image before using Canny to detect edges. My question is: does `cv2.Canny()` do Gaussian blur on its own or it is necessary to apply `cv2.GaussianBlur()` before `cv2.Canny()`? The documentation isn't clear on this point.

Answer (score 7):

Recall that using OpenCV in Python is in fact a wrapper to OpenCV's C++ interface.  The Canny edge detection algorithm's implementation file in C++ can be found here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp

If you examine this source, you can see that there is no blurring done on the image whatsoever.  However, thanks to the correction made by Yves Daoust (see below), the Sobel edge detection algorithm is used for finding the gradient.  There is an `aperture` input parameter that specifies the size of the Sobel kernel.  Using the default means you're using a 3 x 3 kernel and no blurring is applied.  However, anything above 3 x 3 will use a Gaussian kernel.  Therefore, if you want to use the default Sobel kernel, you would need to apply the blurring yourself.  If you vary the size of the Sobel kernel you don't have to perform blurring yourself.

In fact, in the official OpenCV tutorial where they demonstrate the use of Canny, the image is blurred manually prior to the detection: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d5c/tutorial_canny_detector.html.  However, they use a 3 x 3 box filter here prior to the algorithm as you're using a 3 x 3 Sobel kernel.

`tl;dr` - You need to blur the image yourself prior to using the Canny edge detection algorithm if you decide to use the default aperture / Sobel kernel size.  If you go larger than 3, you don't have to blur the image.

Comment: ...which is kinda sad because Canny showed in his seminal paper that Gaussian gradients are the best choice for computing the derivatives, but most implementations either use a Gaussian blur and Sobel filters, or skip the Gaussian blur altogether. OpenCV always prioritizes speed over precision, or even correctness.

Comment: That tutorial is pretty misleading. It advocates a 5x5 Gaussian kernel, though the code uses a 3x3 box filter and calls Canny with a 3x3 aperture !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the hint about the documentation - If you choose a 3 x 3 Sobel kernel in Canny, it does *not* do Gaussian smoothing so now it makes sense to me on why they would presmooth before hand.... however, they should definitely use a Gaussian kernel.  Those docs need to be updated.

Comment: @rayryeng: there is very little difference between Gaussian blur and the blur in Sobel.

Comment: @Yves there is a lot of difference between a Gaussian and the blur in Sobel. Sobel’s kernel uses a 3-tab triangular kernel in the orientation perpendicular to the derivative, and no blurring in the direction of the derivative. I don’t know who came up with larger extensions of the Sobel kernel, or how they are designed. But they are not Sobel kernels, Sobel described a 3x3 kernel, don’t go assigning other random stuff to the man!

Comment: This reminded me of an earlier discussion. Here are my thoughts on these Sobel kernel extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50313678/7328782 (note that I don’t know how OpenCV defines them, the docs don’t say).

Comment: @CrisLuengo: we are talking about the Sobel implementation in OpenCV. By the way, having some lowpass filter is better than nothing, and a perfect Gaussian is not a must.

Answer (score 0):

The `aperture` argument of `Canny` controls the size of the Sobel filter (from 1 to 7 ?), which in fact applies a lowpass filter before taking the derivative. Unfortunately, the documentation is not explicit about that lowpass filter, though Gaussian is cited.

I bet that a binomial filter is in fact used (which is a close approximation to a Gaussian).