# Does cv2.HoughCircles() perform a Gaussian blur?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform, canny-operator

This is an extension to another user’s question asking [whether it is necessary to perform a Gaussian blur before using cv2.Canny()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63543033/15936471). I know from the documentation that cv2.HoughCircles() calls a Canny edge detector (presumably cv2.Canny()). Based on the user’s question, I need to use a Gaussian blur with the default Sobel kernel size. Does cv2.HoughCircles call cv2.Canny() with a default Sobel kernel size? If it does, does cv2.HoughCircles() method implicitly use a Gaussian blur already?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not perform Gaussian Blur.

It is [recommended to apply Gaussian Blur](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d)
before feeding your image to `HoughCircles`.

> It also helps to smooth image a bit unless it's already soft. For example, GaussianBlur() with 7x7 kernel and 1.5x1.5 sigma or similar blurring may help.

In the [current implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/1b07274e34378e83fa7ee67ca794e240f64f832a/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L2242)
of OpenCV there's no Gaussian Blur call.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! I'm looking at the Github page you linked me to, and the HoughCircles() method in C++ seems to accept a parameter "param3". On closer inspection, this "param3", when passed into HoughCirclesGradient(), determines the kernel size for Sobel() and Canny(). Based on the Python documentation, no such parameter "param3" exists in HoughCircles(); does "param3" in Python just default to 3, the standard 3x3 Sobel filter size?

Comment: Ah, I completely missed the next function (void HoughCircles()). That function calls HoughCircles() with param3 = 3, so HoughCirclesGradient calls Sobel() with the standard Sobel kernel size (3x3), which does not apply a Gaussian blur. Thanks for your help!