# How does the Sobel operator expand

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, sobel

I find that kernels for sobel for size 5x5 and 7x7 are also common. But I don't know how to reason.
Is it an extension with binomial expansion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567882/sobel-filter-kernel-of-large-size) might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sobel filter kernel of large size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567882/sobel-filter-kernel-of-large-size)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.